# search: move window below next found line

Tags: search

When I'm searching my document with `/` when the next match line is off screen, the cursor jumps down so that the matched line is the very last line in the window.  For example, if I'm searching for `countWordsWithMap` in [this sample file](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs314/javacode/CodingSamples/WordCount.java), it looks like this:

[image: sample]

Is there any way to make it so the cursor jumps to the line where the match is found, but the window moves below that by a certain amount? For example, if I set the value to 10, the cursor should move to the match on line 59, but the window would jump to line 69, like this:

[image: desire]

Basically, I always want the few lines below the match to be visible, unless the match is at the end of the file.

Comment: `zz` is your friend (see `:h zz`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have an option for that:

```
set scrolloff=10
```

This will always (or at least, when it's possible) leave 10 line above and below the cursor. When scrolling, searching, jumping, ...

It's worth knowing the same for horizontal:

```
set sidescrolloff=10
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can this be made to work in only 1 direction?  i.e. always keep 10 lines below the cursor, but the cursor may be at the top of the window?

Comment: I don't think so, the documentation says explicitly `Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.`